# Use integer in Matrix

Tags: matrix, integer

Language : JAVA

i would to program operation about Matrix" to do LU Decomposition for calculate determinant and..."

I would like to calculate the determinant of a matrix, knowing that I have a matrix of **integers** so to do the calculations, I have to pass by **division**! but I don't have the right to divide two integers.

there will surely mistakes, how do I proceed?

Thank you...

Comment: What programming language are you using?  What formats are your inputs and outputs in?

Comment: i'm with JAVA and i have two dimensional array for in/output to represent  Matrix  : int M[][]= {{5,-6,2,0},{9,0,5,6},{2,3,0,2},{8,9,3,7}};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To divide integer `i` and `j` and produce a floating-point result you can use in your LU decomposition algorithm, typecast one to `double` first:

```
double d;
d = (double)i / j;    //the (double) makes it floating-point.
```

Hope this helps!